# How to say to maven to war a specific folder?

Tags: maven, gwt

In my maven gwt project I want to generate a war version of a specific folder in that project.
I have this codes in my pom.xml :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
```

How to say in plugin element the folder that I want to war it ?

This is my complete pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>Satra</artifactId>
    <groupId>ir.nsdp.satra</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>ir.nsdp.satra</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Satra Web</name>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ir.nsdp.satra.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ir.nsdp.satra.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-shared</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version><dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ir.nsdp.satra.gwt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>test-client</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ir.nsdp.satra.gwt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>test-shared</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>Satra-portlet</warName>

                        <warSourceDirectory>/opt/pros</warSourceDirectory>
                        <archive>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify it as shown below:

```
<warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
```

For step by step description please have a look at [Maven GWT Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/multiproject.html)

Have a look at [warSourceDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceDirectory)

Find sample `pom.xml` at [gwt maven war plugin configuration problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560800/gwt-maven-war-plugin-configuration-problem).

---

--EDIT--

try this one (replace as per your requirement)

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx640M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>eclipse</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <optimizationLevel>9</optimizationLevel>
                <style>DETAILED</style>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <modules>
                    <module>com.x.y.z.EntryPointClassName</module>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</warSourceExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

Comment: how can I call this? I mean what maven command will do this? mvn package is not working!

Comment: I can't say until and unless you share your complete `pom.xml.

Comment: @Obtice I have added my `pom.xml`. Please have a look and let me know once copied.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try that. But before that in my pom.xml, it won't recognize my dependencies

Comment: How to say to include an artifact jar file in my war ?